# JDBC PreparedStatement Seems to Ignore Placeholder

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

Given the following code for a `PreparedStatement`, I use a placeholder (?) to be filled with a `String`:

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(Premium), SUM(AgentComm)\n" +
                "FROM \"?_KLCommissions\" \n" +
                "WHERE AgentCode = \"?\";";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, year);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, agent.getAgentNumber());

    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

When executing the query, however, I get a SQL error: `no such table: ?_KLCommissions`.

Why is the `?` placeholder not being replaced when processing the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it within double-quotes, which means it isn't a placeholder - it's just part of the value.

Beyond that, *most* SQL databases don't let you use parameters for things like table names and column names - only *values* can be parameterised. So you may well need to build the table name part directly, but then use

```
WHERE AgentCode = ?
```

for the agent code - so you'll only have a single parameter to set. So something like:

```
String tableName = year + "_KLCommissions";
// TODO: Put validation here unless you already have *complete confidence*
// that the value of "year" can't be messed around with.
String sql = "SELECT SUM(Premium), SUM(AgentComm) " +
             "FROM " + tableName + " " +
             "WHERE AgentCode = ?";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, agent.getAgentNumber());
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Note the TODO there - you really don't want users to be able to provide an arbitrary value for `year`, as then they could put arbitrary SQL in your query.

Comment: So if, for example, I need to run the statement more than once using a different year, I will actually need multiple statements instead?

Comment: @Zephyr: Yes, you will.

Comment: Note that SQLite doesn't allow table names to start with a digit without escaping the name with double quotes.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I use single quotes to start the table name with an int; that seems to work fine too.

And thank you, Jon. I wasn't aware of the limitation on the placeholders!